# 次の要素へフォーカスを移動（タブキー押下をエミュレート）したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

エンターキー押下など、特定のイベント発生時にタブキー押下と同様の動作（次の要素へフォーカス移動）を行いたいです。

例えば、以下のコードで試したところ、keyup（keyCode = 9）のイベントはトリガーされますが、フォーカスは移動しませんでした。このような `key*` 系のイベントを手動でトリガーしてもフォーカスは移動しないと考えてよいでしょうか。
代替手段としてどのような方法があるでしょうか？

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("keyup", "input", function (e) {
            console.log(e.keyCode);
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var event = $.Event("keyup")
                event.keyCode = 9;
                $(this).trigger(event);
                return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `tabindex`がHTMLタグについていませんが、次の要素とは何を持って指すのでしょうか？

Comment: タブキー押下によってフォーカスが移動する要素です。経験的には html の要素順になるのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

```
このような key* 系のイベントを手動でトリガーしてもフォーカスは移動しないと考えてよいでしょうか。
```

はい。人工的に作られた入力系イベントを投げても、ブラウザのデフォルト動作は起きないと規格で決まっています。

エミュレートするには、[ブラウザが次の要素を探すアルゴリズム](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#sequential-focus-navigation)をJavaScriptで再実装するしかないです。そういうライブラリが既にあるかもしれないですね。

Answer (score 0):

HTMLに読み込まれた要素順であればjquery使えば手っ取り早いです。
選択可能な要素を配列化し、要素にフォーカスするだけかと思います。
ただフォーカス位置についてはグローバルに選択位置を保存するか、
現在のフォーカス状態から位置を割り出すしかないかと思います。

```js
var focusPos = 0;
var sec = 0;
var elements = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  sec = 0;
  elements = $('input[type="text"]:enabled');
  $('input[type="text"]:enabled')
  .focusin(function(e) {
    for(no in elements){
      if(e.target == elements[no]){
        focusPos = no;
        break;
      }
    }
  })
  .focusout(function(e) {
    focusPos=0;
  });
  setInterval(function(){
    sec++;
    if($("#nextFocus").attr("max")<=sec){
      sec=0;
      focusPos++;
      if(elements.length<=focusPos){focusPos=0;}
      elements[focusPos].focus();
    }
    $("#nextFocus").val(sec);
  },1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress id="nextFocus" max="5" value="0"></progress><br />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```